# Background image cannot be seen without text on it in web page

Tags: html, css

I'm still a beginner for web development.For a section in html, an image was set as the background and height was given in css as 100% to take full height also width was give as 50%. Without any text in that section image is not showing.

With text it covers just the row needed for text.When height given in pixels image shows again.What could be the error?

Comment: 100% of what? Without seeing your HTML structure it is impossible to say but it sounds as though the element is being given 100% height of some parent which itself has no height.

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of text. Because of height.

We cannot use height=100% for full screen height. Use `height=100vh` instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you are giving height in % the section takes the minimum height required for the text and hence the image comes for one row .
But as soon as you specify the height in pixels it is a predefined height for the section and is not dependent on the text hence you can see the image.
So you have to give **height=100vh** due to which the section will cover the whole screen height even if there is no text in it.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated to address percentage value calculation**

### `height` of `%` value is calculated based on its parent

When using a `%` value for a `height`, according to [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto.

That is, unless its parent has an explicit height, the child cannot determine the `%` value. Conversely, when you set `height: 100%`, you're saying "100% of the parent height," and without *explicit* parent height, it becomes `height: auto` which then collapses without its own child content or explicit height.

#### Block-level container collapses unless it has content or specific height

By default, any `div`, `section`, or other block-level containers will collapse their height to `0` unless it has *some* content. Also, whatever background image you set up will also not show up, because the container is not rendered.

If there's *small amount* of text (e.g. one line of text), the container will grow only so much, so that the container can envelop the content inside. The background image will show through the given height of the container.

To address this behavior, you could:

- Add a `min-height` to set a minimum height even when there's no to little content, and will grow as needed if the content is bigger
- Add a `height` to set a fixed value of height regardless of the amount of content,
- Add the image as content rather than background, so it could occupy the necessary height. In this case, you'd need to consider other `position` values to place other content in front of the image.

See the code snippet below.

By default all `section` has the default `50%` height value as you noted. Also, each block has a colored border to show its area.

1. First section has no content and no specific `height` or `min-height`. This collapses to `0px` height by default.
2. Second section has a small amount of text content, which increases the container height only by the minimum required amount.
3. Third section has a `min-height` to ensure a minimum space. As you add more content here, the container will grow as needed.
4. Fourth section has a fixed `height` value to `100vh`. This will stay static value, whether you have no content, little content, or a crazy amount of content inside.

```css
*, * > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
section {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/2000);
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
section + section {
  margin-top:10px;
}
.min-height {
  min-height: 200px;
}
.full-viewport {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="empty">
    <!-- no text content here -->
  </section>
  <section class="one-line">
    One line of text here.
  </section>
  <section class="min-height">
  
  </section>
  <section class="full-viewport">
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: You give some workarounds but you do  not answer the question which was why setting a height of 100% does not give the element any height.

Comment: I see. Will update the answer to add it.